# Using hostname rather than IP address in /etc/rsyncd.conf not working

Tags: domain-name-system, rsync, resolve

From what I understand from the rsync docs, I should be able to use a hostname with hosts allow. However, it does not work.

This works:

```
pid file = /var/run/rsyncd.pid
syslog facility = rsync.log
hosts allow = 123.123.123.123
```

This does not work:

```
pid file = /var/run/rsyncd.pid
syslog facility = rsync.log
hosts allow = myaddress.dynalias.org

@ERROR: access denied to devf from unknown (123.123.123.123)
```

If I add the host to /etc/hosts it does work! However, I'm trying to avoid changing it every time my IP address changes by using my dynamic dns hostname.

Is there something I need to do to tell rsync to do a dns lookup rather than just reference the hosts file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have your 'reverse DNS' correctly set up for your host.

Obviously, setting reverse DNS for a dynamic IP is complex. Thus I would recommend to adopt a different `rsync` security strategy (e.g. based on SSH key)

Comment: Well that stinks. SSH is IP restricted also but I have a cron that updates iptables based on my dynamic dns entry. Guess I can do the same kind of thing with rsyncd.conf.

Comment: If you have a cron script, you may also update your `/etc/hosts` to use a FQHN in `rsyncd.conf`